# How to check user is fan (or not) of any page with javascript in my ASP.NET site (without fb app)?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-page

In my ASP.NET site, assume that I have facebook **user_id** and **page_id** and want to determine user like page or not. I found a samples with creating application, then check user like. I dont want that, firstly user login to application, then cheking. Can I check this without application? What should I do for this? Or other advice please.. If witout application it is not possible, so, how can I hide application login window? 
**I want user dont use any application,  dont know I check his likes.**
I need result like this: **yes** or **no**
(Sorry for my bad english)

Answer (score 0):

facebook Fan gate, don't forget to include the javascript sdk in your page

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
    if (response.status == 'connected') {
        var user_id = response.authResponse.userID;
        var page_id = "00"; //page id of the page that should be liked
        var fql_query = "SELECT uid FROM page_fan WHERE page_id =" + page_id + " and uid=" + user_id;
        var the_query = FB.Data.query(fql_query);

        the_query.wait(function (rows) {

            if (rows.length == 1 && rows[0].uid == user_id) {
                //user like page

            }

            else {
                //user not like page

            }
        });
    } else {
        //user not logged in

    }
});

 }
```

Comment: thanks very much, can you edit this code and show it in html code, in working sample, please?

Answer (score 0):

Put it in a .js file and name it something like facebookscript.js and then in include it in 
`<head> <script src="facebookscript.js" type="text/javascript"></script> </head>` like this.

Take a look at this page how to include the javascript sdk: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/  otherwise this code wont work.

if the user isn't logged in or have auth... your app send them to login function like this:

```
function login() {
FB.login(function (response) {
    if (response.authResponse) {
        console.log('Access Token: ' + response.authResponse.accessToken);
    } else {
        console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
    }
}, { scope: 'email' });
}
```

Put the login function where I put the comment tags "//user not like page and  //user not logged in" in my last comment.